# create project in local server with Aptana studio 3 in Linux

Tags: linux, directory, alias, aptana

I am currently installed aptana studio 3 beta in ububntu10.10 and now I have a follow problem(this problem doesn't exists in windows).

I want to create(open) project in(from) my local server using Aptane IDE.
But I can't access to my local server from Aptana studio.

Is there any  advices?

I have an one offer but I don't know linux well and therefore I don't know does this will  work:
Can I create alias(clone) forlder of my project's parent folder in my computer??And when 
I change(add new file,edit file) in my computer,that changes automatically will be occuring 
in server project folder??

Thank's

Answer (score 2):

You could use Aptana Studio 3 Remote view to create a new empty project, then create a FTP connection to your local server and download all the files. To enable auto-upload on local changes, in Project Explorer or App Explorer in context menu select Deploy/Deployment Settings, then check "Automatically sync my changes with the remote site".

If you're working on the same machine as your local server, you could just use the server project location directly in Aptana Studio. To accomplish that, use Project Explorer to find the project location on Local Filesystem. Then "Promote To Project".

Cheers,
Max